# Why can't I set my app to run on startup with Windows IoT?

Tags: boot, pi-2, windows, windows-iot, upstart

I have an app that I would like to have run automatically when my Raspberry Pi 2 starts up.  The Raspberry Pi 2 is running Windows 10 IoT.

I am able to deploy my app and run it with the Visual Studio 2015 debugger. It works great.

However, when I attempt to start it directly using the 'Start' button under 'Apps' on the Raspberry Pi 2 Device Portal (aka IP:8080 on the device) it says it cannot start the application.

Also, when Attempt to set the application as the Default Startup application, it seems to say it worked, but when I restart, the application does not start up.

What special steps are needed to make it so I can deploy and manually run my application on my Raspberry Pi ?

Comment: No special steps are needed. It should just start really.

Comment: I figured out a really easy fix.  I got an arduino and it just works.. :-)  But seriously, what could be causing my Raspberry Pi to NOT start the app, when it works just fine through the Visual Studio 2015 IDE..?  Does it need to be Release mode or something like that?

Comment: hmmm. Dont you have to Publish it to the Pi? Right click on project, Publish and you need select the Pi as the target. Something like that, remembering I am.

Comment: I right click and do a deploy and it succeeds.  The app shows on my Raspberry Pi in the apps menu.  However, when I attempt to start it via the Raspberry Pi local host web view, it just says cannot run.